# Recurring disk-related issues when booting virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, disk, fsck

I'm experiencing a recurring issue with my virtual Ubuntu server. Every three days, this problem occurs exclusively on this particular virtual machine. The server requires a journal recovery, followed by an fsck on `/dev/sda5` to proceed with the boot process. How would I resolve this?

The machine somehow stuck and need to reebot, it can be opened from the web as the server have a web app on it but cant accept login atempts. Thanks

Comment: Hello Egis. How do you shut the VM down? (Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/760077/edit) to provide this information. Do not put it here in the comments.)

Comment: You need to improve this question. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) great guide on how to ask a good question.

Comment: OS & filesystem version? also provide "dmesg -w -T" output